# Passing a page number from one PHP file to another using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I'm working on a website with the following URL structure:

- http://www.mywebsite.com/ is the default home page (same as /index.php?page=1)
- http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=2
- http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=3
- and so on...

I'm trying to pass the current page number from `index.php` to `myphpscript.php` using a javascript function:

```
<script>
function swapContent(filterchoice){
    var PageNum = <?php echo json_encode($_GET["page"]); ?>;
    var url = "myphpscript.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: filterchoice, page : PageNum}, function(data){
        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
</script>
```

On `myphpscript.php`, when adding the following condition for the http://www.mywebsite.com/ case to get `$page_number=1`:

```
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $page_number = $_POST["page"];
}
else {
    $page_number = 1;
}
echo $page_number;
```

It doesn't seem to `echo` anything for the default home page but echo the proper page number for all the other page with `page=` in the URL. However, the `isset` condition seems to work properly on `index.php` even for the default home page with:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page_number = $_GET["page"];
}
else {
    $page_number = 1;
}
```

Could you explain me why it works for the second case and not the first one and how I can set `$page_number=1` in `myphpscript.php` if I'm on the default home page.

Comment: `echo json_encode($_GET["page"])` won't work on home page unless you set `$_GET["page"]` or use `$page_number`. The whole process seems flimsy

Comment: I know it won't work for the home page why is my `isset()` condition not working in `myphpscript.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **check if the `$_GET["page"]` exists** in your first script. If no page is provided (like in your homepage) then your script will look like:

```
<script>
  function swapContent(filterchoice){
    var PageNum = ;
    //...
  }
</script>
```

which is very, very bad.
You should fix it like that:

```
var PageNum = <?= $_GET["page"] ? $_GET["page"] : 1 ?>;
```

it's a *shortcut* conditional statement. It says:

> if `$_GET["page"]` exists, output it. Otherwise, output `1`

Comment: Thank you very much  for your response, I switched my `var PageNum` line for yours, but I still can't see anything when I `echo $_POST["page"];` for my homepage case.

Comment: @LaGuille then look at the source code in browser also inspect the actual ajax request to see what is being sent(in browser console). You don't seem to be doing much in the way of debugging